# XML stored as image in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For reasons that escape me, I have a table that stores xml in an image field. I would like to be able to query that field and see the actual XML

What I currently see is 0xE5E0753F0B0B02457DF74900F5E996DC020F4DB8DF204E9 ... etc

I've tried casting as xml but that doesn't work and I have to leave the table as image so I can't convert it. It stores application source code in an xml framework. I would like to be able to extract it and edit it so I don;t have to use the clunky front end to edit code. Is this possible?

Comment: “I have to leave the table as” … a data type that was deprecated _18 years ago_?

Comment: `IMAGE` can be converted to `VARBINARY(MAX)` (which should be used for all new development), and *that* can be converted to `XML` (or anything else you want). However, given the contents it's unlikely this is actually an `XML`-typed value. You may need to look further into what the application is actually storing (and why it's using an `IMAGE` for that), it may be some compressed or binary representation.

Comment: If you save it to a file, you might be able to run some utils which can guess what kind of file it is (for example in linux there's a file utility). If you post the whole binary string perhaps someone else could help you. It's likely the format is propriatary to avoid hotshots editing it "outside" of their framework

Comment: This is definitely not valid XML in any codepage I know of.

Comment: If you have a working front-end program that converts it to XML profiler might show you how that's done (if it's converted in TSQL).

Comment: That's not plaintext XML. If it were it would probably start with 0x3C3F. If, in fact, it is meant to be XML data then it must be compressed, encrypted, or both.